# Unsigned right shift function not working for negative input

Tags: javascript, php, bit-manipulation

I'm looking for a way to use the `>>>` function from JavaScript in the 64-bit version of PHP 5.5.14. I found [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428382/690573) in my googling:

```
function uRShift($a, $b) 
{ 
    $z = hexdec(80000000); 
    if ($z & $a) 
    { 
        $a = ($a >> 1); 
        $a &= (~$z); 
        $a |= 0x40000000; 
        $a = ($a >> ($b - 1)); 
    } else { 
        $a = ($a >> $b); 
    } 
    return $a; 
}
```

This function seems to work fine for positive numbers, but I get differing results when passing in negative numbers.

For example:

PHP:

```
In: echo uRShift(-672461345, 25);
Out: -149
```

JavaScript (Chrome 35):

```
In: -672461345 >>> 25
Out: 107
```

**EDIT:**

I also tried the other function mentioned in the answer linked above.

```
function uRShift($a, $b)
{
    if($b == 0) return $a;
    return ($a >> $b) & ~(1<<(8*PHP_INT_SIZE-1)>>($b-1));
}
```

PHP:

```
In: echo uRShift(-672461345, 25);
Out: 549755813867
```

[Runnable](http://runnable.com/U72B4paEx3ISuIcp/unsigned-shift-right-bug-demo-for-php)

Comment: You should have used the code in the other answer to that question.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Seems to work fine in PHP 5.4 http://ideone.com/EWmnd4

Comment: Maybe your PHP integers are bigger than JavaScript's?

Comment: ideone is running PHP 5.4.4-12 and it works, Runnable uses 5.4.9 and it doesn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsigned Right Shift / Zero-fill Right Shift in PHP (Java/JavaScript equivalent)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134337/unsigned-right-shift-zero-fill-right-shift-in-php-java-javascript-equivalent)

Answer (score 2):

The constant `0x80000000` (it's written as a call to `hexdec` and stored in the `$z` variable in this example) represents the lowest signed two's complement negative integer (`100000....` in binary). The expression `~$z` should give the bitwise NOT of this, namely, the highest signed positive integer (which ends up being `2147483647`).

The original number (**positive** `0x80000000`, that is, `2147483648`) cannot be stored as a **signed** 32-bit integer, so normally it would be stored as a float of some kind. Unfortunately, PHP 5.5 thinks that `~(2147483648)` is equal to `-2147483649`, which *would be correct if we were dealing with e.g. 64-bit integers*.

And indeed, echoing out `PHP_INT_SIZE` in runnable indicates that integers are 8 bytes, which is 64 bits. Thus, the arithmetic isn't working out right in PHP 5.5.

To remedy this, just replace the `~$z` with a static constant, as follows:

```
function uRShift($a, $b) 
{ 
    if ($a < 0) 
    { 
        $a = ($a >> 1); 
        $a &= 2147483647; 
        $a |= 0x40000000; 
        $a = ($a >> ($b - 1)); 
    } else { 
        $a = ($a >> $b); 
    } 
    return $a; 
}
```

This function still has some weaknesses; for example, shifting by 0 doesn't work properly.