# How do I perform a proper unsigned right shift in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, bit-shift, unsigned-integer

Is this possible to get the same results in PHP and Javascript?

Example:

**Javascript**

```
<script>

function urshift(a, b)
{
  return a >>> b;
}

document.write(urshift(10,3)+"<br />");
document.write(urshift(-10,3)+"<br />");
document.write(urshift(33, 33)+"<br />");
document.write(urshift(-10, -30)+"<br />");
document.write(urshift(-14, 5)+"<br />");

</script>
```

output:

```
1
536870910
16
1073741821
134217727
```

**PHP**

```
function uRShift($a, $b) 
    { 
        if ($a < 0) 
        { 
            $a = ($a >> 1); 
            $a &= 2147483647; 
            $a |= 0x40000000; 
            $a = ($a >> ($b - 1)); 
        } else { 
            $a = ($a >> $b); 
        } 
        return $a; 
    }

echo uRShift(10,3)."<br />";
echo uRShift(-10,3)."<br />";
echo uRShift(33,33)."<br />";
echo uRShift(-10,-30)."<br />";
echo uRShift(-14,5)."<br />";
```

output:

```
1
536870910
0
0
134217727
```

Is this possible to get the same results?

Closest function to what I want is here:

[Unsigned right shift function not working for negative input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659911/unsigned-right-shift-function-not-working-for-negative-input)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsigned Right Shift / Zero-fill Right Shift in PHP (Java/JavaScript equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134337/unsigned-right-shift-zero-fill-right-shift-in-php-java-javascript-equivalent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function unsigned_shift_right($value, $steps) {
    if ($steps == 0) {
         return $value;
    }

    return ($value >> $steps) & ~(1 << (8 * PHP_INT_SIZE - 1) >> ($steps - 1));
}
```

The output, based on your code sample:

```
1
536870910
16
1073741821
134217727
```

Comment: PHP gives me results:

1
2305843009213693950
0
1073741823
576460752303423487

why?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I think I found solution I don't know why but this code works for me:

```
function uRShift($a, $b) 
    { 
        if ($b > 32 || $b < -32) {
            $m = (int)($b/32);
            $b = $b-($m*32);
        }

        if ($b < 0)
            $b = 32 + $b;

        if ($a < 0) 
        { 
            $a = ($a >> 1); 
            $a &= 2147483647; 
            $a |= 0x40000000; 
            $a = ($a >> ($b - 1)); 
        } else { 
            $a = ($a >> $b); 
        } 
        return $a; 
    }
```